# How to Pre-cache Images From list in Flutter

Tags: flutter, image, caching

I am trying to precache all of the images that I have stored in a couple of lists using the Cached Network Image.

I would like the app to cache the image at the start of the app.

I have included what my list of items looks like below.  Any help?
[List image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqvtM.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [precacheImage](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/precacheImage.html) function

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using something like this

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    findImageToCache();
    loading = true;
    super.initState();
  }

  void findImageToCache() {
    Timer(const Duration(microseconds: 1), () async {
      final manifestJson =
          await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('AssetManifest.json');
      List<String> imagePaths = json
          .decode(manifestJson)
          .keys
          .where((String key) => key.startsWith('assets/images'))
          .toList();

      for (int i = 0; i < imagePaths.length; i++) {
        String path = imagePaths[i];
        String filename = (path.split('/').last);
        Image image = Image.asset(path);
        globals.imageCache[filename] = image;
      }
      Timer.periodic(const Duration(milliseconds: 1), precache);
    });
  }

  void precache(Timer t) {
    List<String> keys = globals.imageCache.keys.toList();
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      Image image = globals.imageCache[keys[i]]!;
      precacheImage(image.image, context);
    }
    loading = false;
    t.cancel();
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (loading) {
      return LoadingWidget();
    }
    // the rest
  }
```

To call it, I use

```
Image(image: globals.imageCache["familypicitem.png"]!.image, height: ySize,)
```

I first find all the images in the assets/images
Then I load it to cache